# Changing ComboBox Values From The Controller

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, dictionary, jcombobox

I am Using the Model-View-Controller for a GUI and in the View I have defined an ComboBox with no values. I was wondering how to set the items for the comboBox in the View, from the Controller?

```
public class PlannerController {

    // the model that is being controlled
    private PlannerModel model;
    // the view that is being controlled
    private PlannerView view;

    //variables
    private Map<Route, List<Service>> timetable;

    /**
     * Initialises the Controller for the Journey Planner.
     */
    public PlannerController(PlannerModel model, PlannerView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;


    }   

    class JourneySearchListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                timetable = TimetableReader.read("timetable.txt");
            } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Set the comboBox Values
            Set<Route> comboBoxRoutes = timetable.keySet();
            Object[] comboArray = comboBoxRoutes.toArray();
            /* This is where I want to add the code*/
        }
```

The next class

```
public class PlannerView extends JFrame {

    // the model of the Journey Planner
    private PlannerModel model;
    private JComboBox startStation;
    private JComboBox endStation;

    // REMOVE THIS LINE AND DECLARE ANY ADDITIONAL VARIABLES YOU REQUIRE HERE

    /**
     * Creates a new Journey Planner window.
     */
    public PlannerView(PlannerModel model) {

        //set the default for the model
        this.model = model;
        //Make a way to close the program
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create new container
        Container c = getContentPane();

        //create new frame      
        JFrame thePlanner = new JFrame("Journey Planner");


        //Add elements to interface
        addButtons(c);

    }

/* Helper Methods*/


    private void addButtons(Container c) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        startStation = new JComboBox();
        endStation = new JComboBox();

        p.add(startStation);
        p.add(endStation);
        c.add(p,"North");
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code?  (Please not all of it, just the relevant stuff so we can see what you have so far.)

Comment: @AndrewG ok give me a few seconds let me type up the relevant code

Comment: I would just add either a getComboBox() method to your view that you can access from the controller or make a setComboValues() method in the view that works the same way.  I think the second one would probably follow the design pattern more closely because the controller isn't actually touching any GUI objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing itself uses the MVC-Pattern. JComboBox has it's items in a model, which you can set by `comboBox.setModel(model)`. Provide getters for the two comboboxes, so the controller is able to call `view.getStartStation().setModel(model)`, where `model` is your PlannerModel, which extends `DefaultComboBoxModel`.